# JavaScript simulate keyboard button press CTRL + SHIFT + F in PowerPoint

Tags: javascript, vbscript, macros

I am working on a PowerPoint slide and for some reason I want to add a button/image which would embed a JavaScript to simulate pressing the buttons <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. So when some clicks on the image it would look like some one pressed the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

**I know how it's done with *jQuery* but I need it in *JavaScript* or if anyone knows how to do it with macro's VBScript would be fine too.**

Comment: If you know how to do it in jquery you know how to do it in Javascript as jquery is a javascript framework isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

(Quick answer as I'm away from my desk)

Try the SendKeys function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, it works on the PC but doesn't work when it is published to html/flash for obvious reasons. So i guess i need an actionscript.